# Swift 4 (BETA 2) KVO crashing, based upon WWDC talk

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

I am trying to get something very similar to the example in the WWDC 2017 Foundation talk working for KVO observing. The only differences that I see that are different from that talk are, I had to call super.init(), and I had to make the "kvo" token implicitly unwrapped.

The following is used in a playground:

```
struct Node  {
    let title: String
    let leaf: Bool
    var children: [String: Node] = [:]
}

let t = Node(title:"hello", leaf:false, children:[:])
let k1 = \Node.leaf
let k2 = \Node.children
t[keyPath: k1] // returns "false" works
t[keyPath: k2] // returns "[:]" works

@objcMembers class MyController : NSObject {
    dynamic var tr: Node
    var kvo : NSKeyValueObservation!
    init(t: Node) {
        tr = t
        super.init()
        kvo = observe(\.tr) { object, change in
            print("\(object)  \(change)")
        }
    }
}


let x = MyController(t: t)
x.tr = Node(title:"f", leaf:false, children:[:])
x
```

This error:

> fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath
>   Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath<__lldb_expr_3.MyController,
>   __lldb_expr_3.Node>: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.45.6/src/swift/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift,
>   line 85

Also, see this error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The process has been left at the
>   point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to
>   the state before expression evaluation.

Is anyone else able to get something like this working, or is this a bug I need to report?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The bug here is that the compiler lets you say:

```
@objcMembers class MyController : NSObject {
    dynamic var tr: Node
    // ...
```

`Node` is a `struct`, so cannot be directly represented in Obj-C. However, the compiler still allows you to mark `tr` as `dynamic` – which *requires* `@objc`. While `@objcMembers` infers `@objc` for members of the class, it only does so for members that are directly representable in Obj-C, which `tr` is not.

So really, the compiler shouldn't let you mark `tr` as `dynamic` – I went ahead and [filed a bug here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5317), which [has now been fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/17976) and will be ready for Swift 5.

`tr` *needs* to be `@objc` & `dynamic` for you to use KVO on it, because KVO requires method swizzling, which the Obj-C runtime provides, and Swift runtime doesn't. So to use KVO here you'll need to make `Node` a `class`, and inherit from `NSObject` in order to expose `tr` to Obj-C:

```
class Node : NSObject {

    let title: String
    let leaf: Bool
    var children: [String: Node] = [:]

    init(title: String, leaf: Bool, children: [String: Node]) {
        self.title = title
        self.leaf = leaf
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

(and if you take a look at the WWDC video again, you'll see the property they're observing is in fact of type a `class` that inherits from `NSObject`)

However, in the example you give, you don't really need KVO – you can just keep `Node` as a `struct`, and instead use a property observer:

```
struct Node  {
    let title: String
    let leaf: Bool
    var children: [String: Node] = [:]
}

class MyController : NSObject {

    var tr: Node {
        didSet {
            print("didChange: \(tr)")
        }
    }

    init(t: Node) {
        tr = t
    }
}
let x = MyController(t: Node(title:"hello", leaf:false, children: [:]))
x.tr = Node(title:"f", leaf: false, children: [:])
// didChange: Node(title: "f", leaf: false, children: [:])
```

And because `Node` is a value type, `didSet` will also trigger for any changes to  its properties too:

```
x.tr.children["foo"] = Node(title: "bar", leaf: false, children: [:])
// didChange: Node(title: "f", leaf: false, children: [
//  "foo": kvc_in_playground.Node(title: "bar", leaf: false, children: [:])
// ])
```

Comment: Thanks. I did know about didSet but I was trying out the new KVO stuff.

Comment: All great, except compiler does not complain, and we have a run time crash (possibly after shipping)

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, this is the intended behavior at this time as it depends on the Objective-C runtime. This was their response to my bug report and it further confirms what the accepted answer poster said.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is right. But I want to say what I know about KVO in Swift.

`Swift` also mixing compile `OC` in many Kit and implementation, such as KVO. So, you should know how KVO was implemented in `OC`.

When you `addObserver: forKeyPath:` for a object, The `OC` runtime create a subclass inherit the class that the object belongs to, and then rewrite the `setter` method for the object, when object changed, it call `setter` and `setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)` to notify the change.

Now, let's back to Swift, So your `keyPath` should be a `OC` accepted type.

```
class A {  // it's a Swift class but not a OC class inherit from NSObject
   var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
   @objc dynamic var count: Int = 0  // @objc for OC, dynamic for setter
}

observation = observe(\.count, options: [.new, .old]) { (vc, change) in
   print("new: \(change.newValue), old: \(change.oldValue)")
}  // it's very strange when don't use result, the observe is failure.
```

Above what I know about KVO, and I will search it and update my answer continuously.